# Windows crash(BlueScreen) after continues run/execution of selenium java scripts

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue where my windows crash after few hours of continuous execution of selenium scripts.

I have written a macro using selenium with java script which performing a particular task for me repeatedly. I am using window 7 with 8 GB RAM

I am also using quit method every time when my one phase of iteration done. I have done his to prevent system resources and opening of multiple same browser tabs

Windows shows below stack trace:-

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:   BCCode:   109
>   BCP1: A3A039D8A4DB2A60   BCP2:    0000000000000000
>   BCP3: 13FD9D17BA758C8D   BCP4:    0000000000000101   OS Version:  6_1_7601
>   Service Pack: 1_0   Product:  256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\040317-27066-01.dmp
>   C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-180446-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I have found some article over the internet regarding same but none of them looks relevant or giving proper answer of the problem

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: I have change the setting as per below article. I hope it will work :- 

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-have-blue-screen-issue-irqlnotlessorequal-when-i/015d0311-04d7-4855-af56-92210c1b4f6d

Comment: Also -> http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/

Comment: Are you sure your quit() getting called & executed on each iteration? Sysout some text after quit() & check. Do provide some more information about how you implemented quit(), pure Java or TestNG.

Comment: Hi Dev .. Yes I am using quit with pure java with main method. I am not using TestNG.

Comment: Yes my quit is executing properly and I am quitting browser in my catch block

Comment: that essentially means that the quit() is only called when your try fails. Instead you should quit() at the end of each scenario & start a new browser session. Else there would be a lot of dangling driver instances which is possibly causing Running out of memory.

Comment: I can't do that because it is a business requirement. My script is working perfectly as per the requirement.. Although the selenium should not atleast crash a whole windows OS because of single browser operation. there must be some other reason which is causing this issue.

I am quitting session and starting a new session everytime my catch is executed so there is no reason of lot of dangling driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 7:

1. Go to the Control Panel, choose 'System And Security', and then click 'System', and then click the 'Advanced System Settings' link.
2. In the opened window, click the 'Advanced' tab and then inside the 'Startup And Recovery' frame, click the 'Settings' button.
3. In the opened 'Startup And Recovery' window,  there is 'Write Debugging Information' section. You should set the combo-box in this section to 'Small memory dump', and then click 'ok' to confirm the change.

Source :-

http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/